# Can we get system entities via the DialogFlow API?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using the DialogFlow API to retrieve `intents` and `entities` from sentences. When I define custom `entities`, they are properly returned in the API's JSON response.

However, `System Entities` (which are entities already defined by DialogFlow to cover generic cases like `@sys.date` of `@sys.name`) never show up in the response.

For instance, the sentence : *Hi I'm in France, I'm leaving on Tuesday, January the 1st yeah ?*

Should output two instances of `@sys.date` (for Tuesday and January the 1st), and **they do in the console**, but they don't in the API's response.

Do you know if this is standard, and if not what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

System entities are not available to retrieve via the API.  System entities will still be used to identify entities in user's queries via integration or the API.

In most cases the number of values for a given system entity would make retrieving them unhelpful and impractical.

Comment: Hi, the System Entities actually do show up in the API response IF and only if an Intent is found for the appraised utterance. I had no system entities because my utterance was matched to no intent.
The take away from this is : always have at least a Default Fallback Intent in your agents to be able to retrieve system entities from any utterance

Comment: If an intent is not being matched I'd recommend altering/adding user-says examples to your intent to match the requests you'd like to match.